# UIButton with attributed text not respecting adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift2

Any ideas why UIButton with attributed text set on IB not respecting adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth.

```
 button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 3
 button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
 button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .//tried all options here....
 button.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.2
```

Comment: have u tried this button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;

Comment: where u are setting text for button

Comment: interface builder.

Comment: see image in post. Are you sure that the first line "grows" proportionally with your uibutton?  I don't get the same effect...

Comment: that i know...i'm asking how u wrote in 3 li nes

Answer (score 0):

adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth does not work on attributed string you would have to manually set the appropiate fontsize yourself

Comment: that defeats the purpose of having any attributed text in IB doesn't it? If I set text manually...

Comment: Increase the width of uibutton in ib by hit and trial and adjust your attributed string

Comment: how would that help?

Comment: @GeorgeAsda I'm running into the same problem, is there a solution to this?

Comment: @Moondra I haven’t found it yet.